# Cannot invoke 'registerObserver' with an argument list of type '(ViewController)' - Swift iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am having troubles executing commands when using objective-c code in a swift project with a objective-c-header file.

The error is compile time and says:

```
Cannot invoke 'registerObserver' with an argument list of type '(ViewController)'
```

I am using MDBluetothManager library which is built on BluetoothManager.framework  (Private framework).

The registerObserver method declaration is here:

## MDBluetoothManager.m

```
#pragma mark - Observer methods

- (void)registerObserver:(id<MDBluetoothObserverProtocol>)observer
{
    [self.observers addObject:observer];
}

- (void)unregisterObserver:(id<MDBluetoothObserverProtocol>)observer
{
    [self.observers removeObject:observer];
}
```

## MDBluetoothManager.h

```
- (void)registerObserver:(id<MDBluetoothObserverProtocol>)observer;
- (void)unregisterObserver:(id<MDBluetoothObserverProtocol>)observer;
```

## MDBluetoothObserver.h

```
@protocol MDBluetoothObserverProtocol <NSObject>

@required
- (void)receivedBluetoothNotification:
        (MDBluetoothNotification)bluetoothNotification;
```

In my objective-c project I am executing this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [[MDBluetoothManager sharedInstance] registerObserver:self];

    [self.bluetoothSwitch setOn:[[MDBluetoothManager sharedInstance] bluetoothIsPowered]];
}
```

But when I am doing the same in Swift it doesn't work:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        MDBluetoothManager.sharedInstance().registerObserver(self)
}
```

What could I be missing?

Link to the wrapper class (MDBluetoothManager files) can be found in a example project called BeeTee that I found on github. 
https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee/tree/master/BeeTee

Comment: Is there some errors in compile/runtime? Or just nothing happens when it should?

Comment: The error is at compile time, have updated the description. Thanks

Comment: Which library are you using for this?

Comment: Updated description. The library is MDBluetoothManager which is built on BluetoothManager.framework which is a private API. Although I have succeeded in getting it to work with objective-c.

Comment: Can you show this `registerObserver` method declaration?

Comment: How is registerObserver defined? Especially how is the registerObserver method defined that you are calling, which may not be the one you think you are calling.

Comment: Updated with registerObserver

Comment: Does your ViewController conforms this `MDBluetoothObserverProtocol`? I mean, in declaration of your class is it declared to be implementing this protocol? Looks like compiler checks this one

Comment: No it's not declared. It's just like this: class ViewController: UIViewController {
But I dont think that I am implementing it in objective-c either?

Comment: There is possibility, that this is the problem. Try declaring  `ViewController : UIViewController < MDBluetoothObserverProtocol >`. Anyway, this is a good practice.

Comment: In swift you shouldn't use brackets. But now it's saying with: `class ViewController: UIViewController, MDBluetoothObserverProtocol {` that `Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'MDBluetoothObserverProtocol'`

Comment: That means you haven't implemented functions required by that protocol

Comment: Have you dealt with that case?

Comment: I have implemented the function: `receivedBluetoothNotification`. Now I can build the project, but it crashes when started. I have not done anything inside the function, only println

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81270/discussion-between-simon-nilsson-guldstrand-and-sergii-martynenko-jr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with the help of @Sergii Martynenko JR.

I extended my class with MDBluetoothObserverProtocol:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MDBluetoothObserverProtocol {
```

then I added the necessary functions:

```
func receivedBluetoothNotification(bluetoothNotification: MDBluetoothNotification) {
...
}
```

Then I could register:

```
MDBluetoothManager.sharedInstance().registerObserver(self)
```

Now I have other problems before everything works, but that's another problem. Thanks to all that helped.